# Is it possible to outrank Google for a search term on their own search engine?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, forum

I would like to start a new webmaster forum for my blog site and get it ranked toward the top, but when I check this keyword "webmaster forum", Google is getting the first two first positions (see the screenshot below):

[image: Plese see the image for what I am wanting to say]

If I build a new webmaster forum, it is possible to beat Google and get the number one position on Google search?

Comment: Forget about Google.   You have to defeat `webmasters.stackexchange.com`!   You'll never do it.  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This question is very subjective, but anyway...

> Is it possible to rank higher than Google for the keywords "webmaster forum".

Yes, I imagine it's possible, but *extremely* difficult. You're going to have to build and market something that's bigger and better.

Millions of people use Google products, millions of people have queries regarding those products and `productforums.google.com` have become a go to resource.

> "webmaster forums"

But step back for a moment. This is an incredibly generic search phrase - who/what are you thinking of targeting exactly? For example, search for `HTML webmaster forum` and Google has now gone from the first page of results.

Often users find forums when they are trying to solve specific problems. So, they are searching for specific phrases, not a generic catch-all phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how's this scenario possible. It's better for you to focus on forum and promotion of that forum and numerous other things than getting in front of google in search.

However.... WhatsApp comes up first when you type "web" in google.